# Memory Error with structures in C

Tags: c, strcpy

The code below deletes the contents of `game.answer` in the future and I can't figure out why.

This is the structure:

```
typedef struct
{
   int guesses, guessesAllowed;
   char* answer;
   char max;
} GameState;
```

And this is my function to build a new structure:

```
GameState makeGame(int guessesAllowed, int numOfPositions, char max,
   int seed)
{
   GameState game;
   char answer[9];

   answer[0] = '\0';

   game.guesses = 0;
   game.guessesAllowed = guessesAllowed;
   game.answer = answer;
   game.max = max;

   getAnswer(answer, numOfPositions, max, seed);

   return game;
}
```

I figure it something to do with overriding memory it shouldn't?

Comment: You have a structure containing a pointer. I assume you have properly initialized that pointer? That it points to some in-scope and allocated memory? And can you please try to create a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us (and also copy-paste the complete input and output of the program, together with the *expected* output)?

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory for `game.answer`. You can use `strdup` the first time you input something, and then compare new string length, if length < initial length, use `strcpy` else `strdup`. `strdup` allocates memory for you and copies the string

Comment: You haven't given us a [MCVE]. Is it a ***complete*** example?

Comment: @TheophileDano I just edited my function that I use to create my GameState. If I'm not mistaken I believe this does allocate memory for the game answer.

Comment: @Zach the problem in your "makeGame" function is that you do not heap-allocate your string. `char answer[9];` is just 9 bytes allocated on the stack. Bytes that will later be deleted when the function returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
game.answer = answer;
```

You declared answer as an array *in a function*. You are *not allowed* to keep that address and return it.

The memory of your function and the variables used in it, like `answer` are immediately reused and overwritten.

Comment: It would be useful if you cite the standard chapter that specifies variable scope and lifetime. It is located at *6.2.4 Storage durations of objects* in [this draft document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf).